# Modify the results of JSONObject

Tags: json, jsp

I am getting this response as JSON Object in jsp

```
{"Employeeslist":[{"name":"Decepticons0","id":"19990"},    {"name":"Decepticons1","id":"19991"},{"name":"Decepticons2","id":"19992"},{"name":"Decepticons3","id":"19993"},{"name":"Decepticons4","id":"19994"},{"name":"Decepticons5","id":"19995"},{"name":"Decepticons6","id":"19996"},{"name":"Decepticons7","id":"19997"},{"name":"Decepticons8","id":"19998"},{"name":"Decepticons9","id":"19999"},{"name":"Decepticons10","id":"199910"},{"name":"Decepticons11","id":"199911"},{"name":"Decepticons12","id":"199912"},{"name":"Decepticons13","id":"199913"},{"name":"Decepticons14","id":"199914"}]}
```

But what if I need only :

```
[{"name":"Decepticons0","id":"19990"},{"name":"Decepticons1","id":"19991"},{"name":"Decepticons2","id":"19992"},{"name":"Decepticons3","id":"19993"},{"name":"Decepticons4","id":"19994"},{"name":"Decepticons5","id":"19995"},{"name":"Decepticons6","id":"19996"},{"name":"Decepticons7","id":"19997"},{"name":"Decepticons8","id":"19998"},{"name":"Decepticons9","id":"19999"},{"name":"Decepticons10","id":"199910"},{"name":"Decepticons11","id":"199911"},{"name":"Decepticons12","id":"199912"},{"name":"Decepticons13","id":"199913"},{"name":"Decepticons14","id":"199914"}]
```

In jsp Am doing something like this :

```
            JSONObject json      = new JSONObject();
            JSONArray  employeeslist = new JSONArray();
            JSONObject employee;
            try
            {
                int count = 15;

                for (int i=0 ; i<count ; i++)
                {
                    employee = new JSONObject();
                    employee.put("name"     , "Decepticons" + i);
                    employee.put("id"        , "1999" + i);

                    employeeslist.add(employee);
                 }
                json.put("Employeeslist", employeeslist);
            }
                catch (JSONException jse)
                { 

                }
     System.out.println(json.toString());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace the last line with:

```
System.out.println(employeeslist.toString());
```

This would output the array JSON string alone as required.